# How to encircle two neighbors node using forest?

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

I fail to encircle two node

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %unicode support
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, angles}

\begin{document}
    \forestset{
        circ/.style={
            label={[circle, draw, anchor=south]south:#1}
        }
    }
    \begin{forest}
      for tree={
        edge={-},
        l sep+=7.5pt
      },
        [Foo
            [Bar1, circ=T, name=b1]
            [Bar2, circ=F, name=b2]
            [qux1, circ=T, name=q1]
        ]
    \node[draw,rounded rectangle,fit={ (b1) (b2) }, yshift=-0.5cm] {};
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: current try]

I would like to encircle Bar1, Bar2 and their corresponding circle

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why are you `yshift`ing the `\node`? If I don't do that, Bar1 and Bar2 are encircled, as expected. (Btw, to get the picture you have posted, I had to change the definition of `circ` to `label={[circle, draw, anchor=north]south:#1}`.)

Comment: @SašoŽivanović There must be an easier way to do this, surely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this, although it is rather awkward and not very intuitive because of the difficulties involved in getting things executed in the correct order when they are specified at TikZ options (either implicitly or explicitly). So it is rather messy.

Probably I'm missing a much more obvious strategy. (I think I *must* be missing a much more obvious strategy!)

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}
\forestset{%
  declare count register={clabel},
  clabel'=0,
  circ/.style={%
    clabel'+=1,
    tikz+/.wrap pgfmath arg={%
      \node (label ##1) [circle, draw, anchor=north] at (.south) {#1};
    }{clabel()},
  },
}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={%
    l sep+=7.5pt,
    delay={%
      content/.wrap value={\strut #1},
    }
  },
  [Foo
    [Bar1, circ=T, name=b1]
    [Bar2, circ=F, name=b2]
    [qux1, circ=T, name=q1, tikz+={\node[draw, rounded rectangle, fit=(b1) (b2) (label 1) (label 2), inner xsep=-5pt, inner ysep=1pt] {};}]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: awkward solution]

Comment: Thanks @cfr it is what I expect to get. I tried your mwe but I get some errors as: Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `clabel' (in 'clabel()').

Comment: once I updated forest package I was able to build it. thanks

Comment: Good! I am glad you figured it out. `register`s require a relatively recent version of Forest (v2 or later), it's true, so updating your TeX installation would indeed be the answer.